# IPython.display doesn't show long wav files

Tags: python, audio, jupyter-notebook

I use IPython.display for listening audio file in Jupyter notebook.
I have a long file(30 min).

```
import IPython.display as dis
import numpy
y = numpy.zeros(30*60*48000)
```

This code work as fluidly for 5 seconds

`dis.display(dis.Audio(y[:5*48000], rate=48000))`

but for 30 minutes the code hangs and there are no errors.

`dis.display(dis.Audio(y, rate=48000))`

Is this method not suitable for displaying long audios and is it limited?
Is there another way to display long files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *pydub* library:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
audio = AudioSegment.from_wav("your_audio.wav")
audio
```

Comment: Thank you it's work on audio file with duration 30 minutes